# access specific <td> with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating the following table structure in my web app:

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in computed_report">
      <td>{{ item.website_name }}</td>
      <td class="editable" :class="{green: is_by_user(item['adsense_source'])}" v-on:dblclick="set_custom(item, 'income_adsense')">{{ item.income_adsense }}</td>
      <td class="editable" :class="{green: is_by_user(item['taboola_source'])}" v-on:dblclick="set_custom(item, 'income_taboola')">{{ item.income_taboola  }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now each item has a unique property : `item.site_id` , so `set_custom(item,key)` can tell the row number using the site_id and the key is the name of the column. problem is i have no idea how can i manipulate the `<td>` in a vue.js way. so let's say inside `set_custom(item,key)`  i want to add a class  to the `td` in the `item.site_id` row and the `key` column, how can i achive that?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking jQuery way. This is VueJS. VueJS working in different way than jQuery where you can refer to some element using `$('#id')`.

Your question is quite not clear, but I will try to explain.
The best what you can do is in my opinion use method with your parameters(item,key) which will throw true/false depend on those values and use this method to bind the class.

So in thic case your code would look like: `<td v-bind:class="[yourMethod(key,item)? trueClass : falseClass]">`